# Restful webservice deployed on http port of Glass Fish Server 3.1.2 is not responding

Tags: jersey, glassfish-3, restful-url

We have deployed a RESTful web service (using Jersey 1.18) on http port of glass fish server 3.1.2. After responding to few requests the web service hangs and will not respond to any requests for few minutes. It recovers on its own after few minutes. No information / error found in the logs during the down time. what could be the possible cause for this? we are looking for high availability of this web service.

Comment: Everything which blocks (async) could be a reason, maybe connection pool/entity-manager/db, any future or something else. Did you checked that?

Comment: I have checked, there are no database connection leaks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is located. It is because of the size of http thread pool. It was set to a max of 5. It is now enhanced and the application is behaving as expected. Below is a reference URL helped in identifying the issue.

[Monitoring in glass fish](https://blogs.oracle.com/binublog/entry/monitoring_in_glassfish)